# How can I add a user through SQL?

Tags: users, mysql

By mistake I just ran this query:  (note the extra `;`)

```
DELETE FROM wp_users; WHERE ID = 321;
```

How can I add a user through SQL?

I searched around but couldn't find a proper answer to this fairly simple question.

More info about the situation I was in when I asked this:

- Can't use `wp-cli` on this shared hosting environment and it's way easier to launch `mysql` than to figure out how to run some PHP.
- I was not logged into the site (so I can't log in anymore).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will create a new admin user called username with password: password in a database called DATABASE with table prefix wp_

Change the two accordingly to your own database name and table prefix.

Try this:

First create a row in `wp_users`. Replace DATABASE with your database name, username with your choosen username, password with your password of choice.

```
INSERT INTO `DATABASE`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, 
`user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_registered`,
`user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('9999', 
'username', MD5('password'), 'nickname', 'email@example.com', '', 
'2014-11-04 00:00:00', '', '0', 'username');
```

Next insert two rows into `wp_usermeta`. Replace `DATABASE` with your database.

```
INSERT INTO `DATABASE`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`,
`meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '9999', 'wp_capabilities', 
'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}'), (NULL, '9999', 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

The key 9999 is a unique ID number so choose something that is not used.

Comment: oh yeah if you wanna use phpmyadmin look here:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

Comment: This wasn't working for me for the fact that i forgot the change the wp_ part in wp_capabilities. The wp_ should be your database prefix

Comment: I've updated answer to reflect your concern @NMENewMediaEntertainment

Answer (score 3):

Generally, WordPress has functions to handle what you want, it is much preferable to use them. For example, because it isn't a complete list, some of those are:

- [`wp_delete_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user)
- [`wp_create_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)
- [`wp_insert_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)
- [`wp_update_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user)

The class behind (most of) it is:

- [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User)

If you really need to know the SQL that is used, I would suggest you read the according source files. But as I said, it is much preferable to use the possibilities WordPress already offers, instead of doing your own custom SQL.

Comment: How am I supposed to run these functions? I wasn't able to login to the site.

Comment: You can run them for example from the `functions.php` or a (mu-)plugin. Aside from that, how should I know you aren't able to login to your site. @KasperSouren

Comment: @KasperSouren please add that info to your question, does this mean you can't log into WP or does it mean you don't have  ftp/ssh/cpanel access?

Comment: How can I log in to a site with an empty `wp_users`? :)
What is "the `functions.php`" and how do I use it? Is it possible to use from the command line? Please add more info. I've been using WP for 8 years or so but I don't know what you mean here so I can't accept this answer.

Comment: In fact, I thought the "through SQL" part of the question title was pretty clear.

Comment: Yea, you know many people request SQL solutions, but almost all of them can be done better and easier another way. Again, your question did not say anything about being unable to login or having a empty `wp_users` table, so excuse me if I haven't considered this. About your additional need for information, take a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) for starters, if you want to know to more you'll find it. @KasperSouren

Comment: It didn't say those things explicitly, but it did explicitly say `DELETE FROM wp_users;`...